# In excel, I need to find the maximum date based on the employee number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried to use the following formula when trying to find the max date of these columns based on the employee number in my hundreds of thousands lines of data.  The formula bar gives me 'yes' when it is the max, however in my cell it says 'no'.  I cannot figure out what the issue is.  Thanks for the help.
Tamara

[Excel Max date formula Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXatg.jpg)

```
Formula used:  =IF(AQ2=MAX(IF($C:$C=C2,$AQ:$AQ)),"YES","NO")  

    A                 B     Employee Number   Max?
11-Mar-13         12-Mar-13 199               NO
24-Mar-13         26-Mar-13 199               NO
1-Aug-13           6-Aug-13 199               NO
22-Dec-13         27-Dec-13 199               NO
15-Apr-13         17-Apr-13 206               NO
18-Apr-13         18-Apr-13 206               NO
8-Aug-13          10-Aug-13 206               NO
17-Oct-13         18-Oct-13 206               NO
25-Dec-13         20-Feb-14 206               YES
8-May-13           8-May-13 214               NO
```

Comment: have you evaluated your formula by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER? As I see it should work if your dates are in column `AQ`

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this without an array is all of the dates for a specific employee ID are unique--that is, you won't have two of the same date. In this case, the following formula will check that (a) the number of dates with employee ID is equal to (b) the number of dates with employee ID that are less than or equal to the current employee ID. This will only be true for the "max" date for said employee id:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($C:$C,C2)=COUNTIFS($C:$C,C2,$A:$A,"<="&A2),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find the set of dates with the largest time span in between said dates. If this is the case, then I would recommend using two seperate fucntions, the `=DAYS360` function and the `=MAX` function.

I have re-created your sheet and it will end up looking similar to this:
[image]

Here is the same picture of the same sheet with functions revealed, so that you can see how the functions are used:
[image]

The =DAYS360 function takes two inputs, and return the number of days in between two dates. The max function simply finds the largest number in a range. Please let me know if this helped.

EDIT: Also, if you want to see the actual word Max next to the largest date range, you can nest the `Max` fucntion from my column E within an `If` function, like this:

```
=IF(MAX(D:D)=D2,"Max","")
```

Comment: Did this help at all? Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, do you want "YES" to appear for each employee's max date range?  Assuming column `AQ` contains the spans between dates in columns `A` and `B` (i.e. `=B2-A2` copied down), your formula should work.

This only works as an array formula, so make sure you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when entering the formula, then copy it down to all cells in the same column.

`=IF(AQ2=MAX(IF($C:$C=C2,$AQ:$AQ)),"YES","NO")`, entered in D2 using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>and copied down produces the following:

```
A           B           C       D   ...     AQ
11-Mar-13   12-Mar-13   199     NO          1
24-Mar-13   26-Mar-13   199     NO          2
1-Aug-13    6-Aug-13    199     YES         5
22-Dec-13   27-Dec-13   199     YES         5
15-Apr-13   17-Apr-13   206     NO          2
18-Apr-13   18-Apr-13   206     NO          0
8-Aug-13    10-Aug-13   206     NO          2
17-Oct-13   18-Oct-13   206     NO          1
25-Dec-13   20-Feb-14   206     YES         57
8-May-13    8-May-13    214     YES         0
```

If you are simply looking for the greatest date range, the formula `=IF(E2=MAX($E:$E),"YES","NO")` entered in `D2` and copied down will do the trick.